# Service Principals and CRL checking

Tags: azure-active-directory

Does a Service Principal (SP) check the CRL for the cert that is used to authenticate the SP?

I have a client that is concerned over the use of SP with Certificates for authentication and wants to understand what happens if the certificate used for authentication is revoked.

Answer (score 0):

Service Principal checks the "Certificate Revocation List" (CRL). To revoke a client certificate, Azure Active Directory fetches the certificate revocation list (CRL) from the URLs uploaded as part of certificate authority information and caches it. The last publish timestamp in the CRL is used to ensure the CRL is still valid. The CRL is periodically referenced to revoke access to certificates that are a part of the list.

To configure the certificate in Service principal, you can create certificate locally and go to the manifest of Service Principal and update the KeyCredential part like below:

[image]
Below is the documentation link for configuring revocation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/active-directory-certificate-based-authentication-get-started#step-3-configure-revocation

I hope it helps.

Comment: No, ServicePrincipals client certificate flow does not check CRL. If it did, how would self-signed certs work? AAD only validates the cert date range and does not check other cert properties